# Function pairs for which $f(x)=g(y)\iff f(y)=g(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I came across recently a rather interesting result that for $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$: $$\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1-x_2}=\frac {y_1}{y_2} \iff \frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{y_1+y_2}{y_1-y_2}$$
In other words the two functions $f,g: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R; f(x)=\frac{x_1}{x_2}, g(x)=\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1-x_2}$ have the rather special property that $f(x)=g(y)\iff f(y)=g(x)$. This motivated me to try to find more such pairs of functions. Obviously, $g=f$ results in a trivial solution, so I discard those cases.

So far in $\Bbb R$ I found $$f(x)=Ax+B, g(x)=C-Ax; A,B,C \in \Bbb R$$

$$f(x)=A\ln(s_1(x)), g(x)=A\ln(s_2(x)); A\in \Bbb R$$

where $s_1,s_2$ satisfy $s_1\circ s_2=s_2 \circ s_1$ and are self-inverse. To my knowledge, this requires $s_1(x)=x$ and $s_2$ any self-inverse function, but I'm not certain on that point.

I find this property fascinating, and welcome all contributions towards finding more pairs of functions that fit it.

Comment: If $f,g$ are bijections, this is the same as requiring that $g^{-1}f$ is an involution.

Comment: $f$ can be anything if we define $g(y)=1-f(y)$. Replace $1$ with any constant $A$ if you like. For example $f(x)=\sin^2x$, $g(x)=\cos^2x$.